# Facebook plugins I like - where does it take infos about title/description/photo?

Tags: html, facebook, social-networking

When I do an "I Like" on a website with the facebook plugins, I see on Facebook there is the Title of that page, a description, an image, and so on...

If I try to put the plugins on my website and do an "I Like", I can only see title on  of the main page, nothing more!

On which tag need I to insert the image path, description, and a custom title?
Actually, my doctype is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

so, not an HTML5 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should readup on the [Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).
Essentially you'll need to embed some `og:tags` onto your page so that Facebook can know what information to display for the preview of the like action.
The tags should be placed within your `head` tag and they look something like this :

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="YOUR_NAMESPACE:recipe" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR_PAGE_TITLE" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="YOUR_IMAGE_URL" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="YOUR_DESCRIPTION_TEXT" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="YOUR_URL">
```

Don't forget to substitute the values there for your own values.
If you are having difficulties in choosing what tags to use or what values to use - you should check out  this great tool that Facebook has provided us : 
[Facebook's URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)
This tool will show you exactly how Facebook views your URL and it will also alert you to any errors that you might have with your `og:tags`.

---

Be aware of the caching that Facebook does of your tags :
Taken from the [Open Graph Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/)

> **Editing Meta Tags**
>
> You can update the attributes of your page by updating your page's
>    tags. Note that og:title and og:type are only editable
>   initially - after your page receives 50 likes the title becomes fixed,
>   and after your page receives 10,000 likes the type becomes fixed.
>   These properties are fixed to avoid surprising users who have liked
>   the page already. Changing the title or type tags after these limits
>   are reached does nothing, your page retains the original title and
>   type.
>
> For the changes to be reflected on Facebook, you must force your page
>   to be scraped. The page is scraped when an admin for the page clicks
>   the Like button or when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL
>   Linter.

Comment: But I need all of these tags! Tried to put (for example) only <meta property="og:image" content="www.mywebsite.com/img/preview.jpg" /> but in fact nothing change...

Comment: Same for title : <meta property="og:title" content="My Titlez" /> it is not showed on Facebook :(

Comment: Great links! Expect for 2 warnings The og:url property should be explicitly provided and The og:locale property should be explicitly provided it seems to get the correct data there. It is on facebook that it doesnt show data...

Comment: can you post a link to the URL in question so we can see for ourselves?

Comment: oh...looks like it works now :O Maybe it should refresh? Dunno!

Comment: yea, it might take a minute or two to update..  if you found my solution helpful, you should consider marking your question as answered. :)

Comment: Would be nice if I could place this tags everywhere, not on <head> tag :)

Comment: The `og:tags` are on a per-URL basis - you essentially don't have to put the meta tags on the same URL as the main page.  Your like button could be connected to a different URL within your site and then you'd put the `og:tags` on that URL instead...

Comment: Tried, in the middle of the page (before render the Plugins for Facebook) to append these meta-tag to the header, but in fact It can't render it! Do you know why? Or do you have a strategy?

Comment: I think this is a different question - why don't you [post another question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) regarding the placement of the `og:tags`...